# how to add multiple values from multiple hashes with same key (perl)

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Hello people im trying to add multiple values from multiple hashes with same key.

And this is the result of scheme that I want acomplish.

```
 HASH1 => { 
   '2016-07-01' => { 'val1' => '7',  'val2' => '9', },
   '2016-07-02' => { 'val1' => '10', 'val2' => '6', } }
 HASH2 => { 
   '2016-07-01' => { 'val1' => '8',  'val2' => '4', },
   '2016-07-03' => { 'val1' => '3',  'val2' => '2', } }

 HASH3 => { 
   '2016-07-01' => { 'val1' => '6',  'val2' => '5', },
   '2016-07-02' => { 'val1' => '1',  'val2' => '2', }, 
   '2016-07-04' => { 'val1' => '4',  'val2' => '2', } }

 OUTPUT HASH => { 
   '2016-07-01' => { 'val1' => '21', 'val2' => '18', }, 
   '2016-07-02' => { 'val1' => '11', 'val2' => '8', }, 
   '2016-07-03' => { 'val1' => '3',  'val2' => '2', }, 
   '2016-07-04' => { 'val1' => '4',  'val2' => '2', }, }
```

Im trying pushing duplicate keys to an array to identify each one, then add values.
This i'm trying is for compare 2 hashes, but i want make it for multiple hashes.

```
my @common = ();
foreach (keys %HASH1) {
push(@common, $_) if exists $HASH2{$_};
}
foreach my $DUP_KEY (@common){
my $v1 = $HASH1{$DUP_KEY}{'val1'} + $HASH2{$DUP_KEY}{'val1'};
my $v2 = $HASH1{$DUP_KEY}{'val2'} + $HASH2{$DUP_KEY}{'val2'};
$HASH1{$DUP_KEY}{'val1'} = $v1;
$HASH1{$DUP_KEY}{'val2'} = $v2;
}

my %OUT_HASH = (%HASH1, %HASH2);


foreach my $key (keys %OUT_HASH) {push(@ARR, $key);}
foreach (sort @ARR) {push(@ARR_CLEAN, $_);
}
```

but the result is not as expected, because im getting only the duplicates keys only.

someone would be so kind as to help me? thank you!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you try to do. Do you want to sum up all values with the same key from a bunch of hashes? Where do the duplicates come into play?

Comment: '2016-07-01' dates is the 'main keys' example. and i want join all hashes and sum up the values with same key. its a little confuse i know. thank you - edited (there up is the IN data hashes and the OUT hash i want to acomplish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up the hashes of hashes, loop over all the hashes, over their first keys (here the date), then over the second key (here the value). Sum up the numbers in a new hash.

I'd move the code to sum the values to its own sub for clarity, then pass it the references of the hashes you want to sum up.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

sub sum {
    my %sums;
    foreach my $hash (@_) {
        foreach my $date (keys %{$hash}) {
            foreach my $val (keys %{$$hash{$date}}) {
                $sums{$date}{$val} += $$hash{$date}{$val};
            }
        }
    }
    return %sums;
}


my %HASH1 = (
    '2016-07-01' => {'val1' => '7', 'val2' => '9'}, 
    '2016-07-02' => {'val1' => '10', 'val2' => '6'}
);
my %HASH2 = (
    '2016-07-01' => {'val1' => '8', 'val2' => '4'}, 
    '2016-07-03' => {'val1' => '3', 'val2' => '2'}
);
my %HASH3 = ( 
    '2016-07-01' => {'val1' => '6', 'val2' => '5'}, 
    '2016-07-02' => {'val1' => '1', 'val2' => '6'}, 
    '2016-07-04' => {'val1' => '4', 'val2' => '2'} 
);

my %sums = sum(\%HASH1, \%HASH2, \%HASH3);
foreach my $date (sort keys %sums) {
    print "$date\n";
    foreach my $val (keys %{$sums{$date}}) {
        print "    $val: $sums{$date}{$val}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: humm im getting error: Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not hash element) at .... near "}) .... its on line #8 and #34...  im using perl version 5.14.1 it is because my perl version ? thank you Robert

Comment: It works for me in 5.18.2. I've added extra `%{...}` around the hashes in line 8 and 34. Does that fix it?